# why runtime error on io.WriterString?

Tags: io, go

I get a "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" when running the following code. I do not understand why and cant seem to catch the error from the io.WriteString(w, s) where I believe the problem resides. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
package main

import(
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "hei"
    var w io.Writer
    _, err := io.WriteString(w, s)
    if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(s)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add

```
fmt.Println(w)
```

right after `var w io.Writer`, you'll see that what gets printed is `<nil>`. This means you're just creating a variable but not initializing it to a real value. You then attempt to pass it to a function that needs a real `io.Writer` object but gets a nil.

Also, `io.Writer` is an interface (see http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer), so you need to find a concrete implementation of it (such as `os.Stdout`) to be able to instantiate it.

For more information about the `io` package, see http://golang.org/pkg/io/.

**P.S.** perhaps you're confusing this with C++; in C++, when you do `io::Writer w`, then `w` automatically gets initialized to contain a fresh copy of `io::Writer`, however, the Go code `var w io.Writer` is really equivalent to `io::Writer* w` in C++, and it's obvious that `w` in that case will contain `null` or more probably some indeterministic garbage. (Go guarantees that it's `null` though).

Answer (score 2):

```
var w io.Writer
```

initializes `w` to a `nil` writer. You need to point it to an actual writer to do anything useful with it, e.g.

```
w = os.Stdout
```